# Can't generate firebase custom token

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have followed this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup

I have created my key and received my *.json file. I also have this code with the required npm packages installed.

```
var http = require('http');
var httpdispatcher = require('httpdispatcher');
var firebase = require('firebase');

firebase.initializeApp({
  serviceAccount: "<my-service-account>.json",
  databaseURL: "https://<project-id>.firebaseio.com"
});

const PORT=8080; 

httpdispatcher.onGet("/firebaseCustomToken", function(req, res) {
    var uid = req.params.uid;

    if (uid) {
        var customToken = firebase.auth().createCustomToken(uid);
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.end(JSON.stringify({'firebaseJWT' : customToken}));
    } else {
        res.writeHead(400, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('No uid parameter specified');
    }
});    

function handleRequest(request, response){
     try {
        //log the request on console
        console.log(request.url);
        //Disptach
        httpdispatcher.dispatch(request, response);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }    
}

//create a server
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

//start our server
server.listen(PORT, function(){       
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```

However when sending a GET request to /firebaseCustomToken?uid=123456 I receive this error

```
[Error: error:0906D066:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad end line]
```

I have read this could be to do with the formatting of the private key, but how could this be as I haven't modified the file recieved from the firebase console?

Comment: And you have actually changed this part right `<my-service-account>.json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PEM is the key to access Firebase which you should have downloaded in the .json file. It could be the path to your .json file is incorrect.

You will likely run into another error if you fix this though. Firebase and the server establish a websocket connection. When createCustomToken() is called, the token is generated and known to firebase via the websocket connection. You send the token to the client requesting authentication in response to the client request. The client then signs in by calling .signInWithCustomToken(token).

You'll need to configure and initialize firebase on the client side too. Check out the web, iOS, or android documentation.

Let me know if you can't get it working, I can post some code snippets tomorrow.

Comment: I just fired it up again tonight didn't change anything and it worked! Very strange maybe a propagation thing on the firebase end?? - Thanks for answer though